# The value from the function is returned after the variable is output to the console

Tags: javascript

In the loop, I call the function and pass it the identifier, after which the function should return the vacancy to me.

```
const Profile = require('upwork-api/lib/routers/jobs/profile.js').Profile;
...
let jobsDetails = [];
for (let valueKeys of Object.values(arrayOfJobs)) {
    getJobDitalis(api, valueKeys, (error, data) => {
        console.log(data.profile)
        jobsDetails.push(`${data.profile}`);
    });
    console.log(jobsDetails)
}
...
function getJobDitalis(api, key, callback) {
    const profile = new Profile(api);
    profile.getSpecific(key, (error, data) => {
        callback(error, data);
    });
}
```

But for some reason, first an empty object is displayed in the console, and then only information about the vacancy. That is, `console.log (jobsDetails)` is fired first, and then only `console.log (data.profile)`

```
[]
[]
[]
{job}
{job}
{job}
```

Why it happens? What is my mistake?

Comment: getJobDetalis is async function so console.log(data.profile) will run after complete of async request  whereas console.log(jobsDetails) run immediately

Comment: @Arshpreet Wadehra How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Looks like it's a callback

Comment: @MegaRoks whats your requirement? you want to make getJobDitalis synchronous?

Comment: @Arshpreet Wadehra I want `console.log (jobsDetails)` to have job details, not an empty object.

Comment: you can move console.log(jobsDetails) inside getJobDitalis callback there it will run n time and console updated value each time, or if you want to access jobsDetails after end of for loop then we have to make it synchronous. 
Does getting jobDetails inside callback solve the problem?

Comment: yes as @ArshpreetWadehra said  jobsDetails is being consoled outside the asyn functions which takes time to complete.. In the meanwhile loop iterates and console the empty jobDetails Array

Comment: @Arshpreet Wadehra I want the getJobDitalis function to be made synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using async await you can make your async task synchronous.

I don't know about your code structure, but I tried to make a solution from the given data.

```
function getJobDitalis(api, key, callback) {
    const profile = new Profile(api);
    profile.getSpecific(key, (error, data) => {
        callback(error, data);
    });
}
...
(async ()=> {
let jobDetails = [];
for (let valueKeys of Object.values(arrayOfJobs)) {
const profile = await new Promise(resolve=>{
    getJobDitalis(api, valueKeys, (error, data) => {
        console.log(data.profile)
        resolve(data.profile);
    });
  })
 jobDetails.push(profile)
}
 console.log(jobDetails); 
 //do your task with jobDetails
})()
```

I made [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) async function.

Answer (score 0):

Flow (let's assume a single iteration of the `for` loop):

```
getJobDetalis(api, key, callback)
    profile.getSpecific(key, func)
        func(error, data)
            callback(error, data)
                console.log(data.profile)
console.log(jobsDetails)
```

However, `profile.getSpecific` does not necessarily wait for `func` to complete.

And since the 1st print is executed from the call-stack of `func`, it will not necessarily occur before the 2nd print.

Comment: How do I get the getJobDitalis function to be synchronous?

Comment: @MegaRoks: It probably returns a `Promise`, which you need to resolve.